# Kotlin hide replaced fragments don't work

Tags: android, kotlin, replace, fragment, hide

I have a fragment with constraints that I want to preserve

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fr_test"
    android:name="com.test.FragmentTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I use transactions to hide/show it and all . works fine

```
fm.beginTransaction().hide(mainActivity.fr_test).commit()
fm.beginTransaction().show(mainActivity.fr_test).commit()
```

I use transactions to recreate fragment keeping the same container to use the same constraints

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivity.fr_test, FragmentTest).commit()
```

But if now I try to hide/show the fragment with the same references as before it does nothing. I suppose that references are lost but I don't know how to find them. I tried to save the reference like this:

```
fragRef = FragmentTest()
viewsManager.fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fr_test, fragRef).commit()
```

and then use:

```
fm.beginTransaction().hide(mainActivity.fragRef).commit()
fm.beginTransaction().show(mainActivity.fragRef).commit()
```

but still does the same.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can use a FrameLayout to replace/show/hide fragments.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout

Comment: I use ConstraintLayout for that the problem is not how to hide, the problem is hide a replaced fragment, after replace it works fine

Answer (score 0):

When you call `replace`, he calling `remove(fragment)` and after call `add(int, fragment, string)`. I think that you should use `add` method instead `replace` and control your UI using `hide` and `show`

Comment: I know that, but if I only add I don't remove the old fragment, my problem is that sometimes I want to hide/show and sometimes I want to reset the fragment so I recreate. hide/show works fine till the moment I replace. then reference is lost and I can't show/hide

Comment: If you need to show/hide only, call this and add New fragment. If you need reset, call remove separately before add. No?

Comment: I suppose that this will be the fact, my first fragment is not added dynamically with add, it is directly in xml. problably I should remove it from xml and add it dynamically, then reference will be not lost. I will try it later. I was doing that for reuse the constraints of the fragment in the container